# Where to find Pod API of Kubernetes?

Tags: api, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I read
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/pods.html
and the last paragraph shows a link to Pod API which is broken.
Does anybody know how to get there?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github organization where Kubernetes is developed changed (from "GoogleCloudPlatform" to "kubernetes") after these docs were generated. That broke the link. I think you can find the reference here: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/api-reference/definitions.html#_v1_pod

And the source for that here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/api-reference